# How can I achieve the text animation like this website https://uniqualitech.com/ which goes from baseline to reveal using CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I tried this one which I found online, but doesn't seem to look like that, but is close to it. Also, when I increase the amount of text, it looks totally different.

```
<h1>
  <span class="text">Hello, World!</span>
</h1>

    h1 {
  overflow: hidden;
}
h1 .text {
  font-family:-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,Oxygen-Sans,Ubuntu,Cantarell,"Helvetica Neue",sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  animation: baseline 0.5s forwards cubic-bezier(.4,0,.39,1.04);
}
@keyframes baseline {
  0% { transform: translateY(140%); }
  100% { transform: translateY(0); }
}

/* Just for basic styles */
html {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
body {
  color: white;
  background: #37474f
  ; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your question and it's totally simple if you're talking about the very first heading.

if you open your browser's inspector and see the codes that they have used, you can see that it's not just one text, for 4 lines of their texts they have used a separate `div` and `h1`, but you have written only one `h1`.

Comment: can you edit the above code and make it animate like https://uniqualitech.com/, I am a noob in CSS. Thanks in advance